# Run Jenkins ant build within special shell environment

Tags: ant, hudson, jenkins

Our internal build system uses a shell script to setup the environment for building projects. Then the actual build tools (ant or make) can reference environment variables for configuring various things. In essence, it does:

```
$ /path/to/setup_env.sh .
[build env] $ ant compile
```

Note that the first command launches and initializes a new shell and expects all subsequent build operations to be performed in that shell.

Now I am trying to replicate the same within Jenkins. How do I run a shell script and then have the subsequent ant build step take place in the same environment?

The 'Execute Shell' built-in as well as the EnvInject plugin didn't help since they discard any changes to the environment before moving to the next build step.

I'd prefer not to modify the ant build file since the same should continue to work in the current internal build system.

Comment: Have you tried putting both items into one build step? Combining them into one shell script?

Comment: The problem is that the first step launches a new shell and expects the subsequent steps to be performed within that shell. I'm going to update the question with this detail..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a "solution" that worked out for us. The key idea is that the `setup_env.sh` script launches a new shell in which it exports a bunch of environment variables. What we needed was access to those variable definitions. So we did a three part Jenkins Build:

#### Step 1 - Execute Shell

Use the 'Execute Shell' Jenkins built-in to run our `setup_env.sh` script. Then feed the newly launched shell a simple python script that dumps the environment to a file.

```
/path/to/setup_env.sh . <<< 'python <<SC
print "Exporting env to buildenv.properties file"
import os
f = open("buildenv.properties", "w")
env = os.environ
for k in env:
  f.write("%s=%s\n" % (k, env[k]))
f.close()
print "Done exporting env"
SC'
```

#### Step 2 - Inject Environment Variables

Now we use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to inject environment variables from the file dumped in the previous step. The config here is simple, just specify the dumped properties file name as the `Properties File Path` field value.

#### Step 3 - Invoke Ant

Here, we kick off the normal `ant` build. Since the environment now contains all the required definitions, the build completes as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Comment: How exactly do I use EnvInject? When running a shell script with EnvInject, it doesn't actually retain any environment modifications performed by the script. This is documented behaviour.

Comment: I should've guessed as much - otherwise the question does not make sense. You can slightly rewrite the shell script that it would accept a parameter that would tell it not to start a subshell and to exit in the end (let's call it `andexit`). Then you say: `source setup_env.sh andexit`. The environment variables are now in the parent shell. People still can use it in the old way without that parameter.

Comment: "You can slightly rewrite the shell script" - if only!! :-)

Comment: If you solve your problem in some elegant please publish your solution and 'ping' me.

Comment: Cool! I thought of an idea of somehow exporting the variables to a file, but did not know that you can 'inject' executables into a script. In fact, I'm unfamiliar with '<<<' syntax. Thanks!